# Set up OpenVPN via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, openvpn

So I recently bought a Linux server (Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)). I only bought this server to use it as a VPN-Server. But it seems to be more complicated than I thought. I mean I don't want to learn Linux, I just want to set up OpenVPN that's it...
Connecting to the server via SSH using Putty (from Windows 8.1) worked just fine.
But even though I [found a step by step tutorial](http://spielprinzip.com/blog/allgemein/installing-openvpn-and-connect-via-ssh-to-a-remote-machine/) for installing OpenVPN, I'm having a lot of trouble following it.

> sudo apt-get install openvpn

I couldn't use sudo. So I just didn't use it. I'm on the root account though, in case that matters.

> mkdir /home/root/openvpn

This command returned 'cannot create directory'. I googled it and used `mkdir -p /home/root/openvpn` instead, which returned nothing, so I assume it's fine.

> vim /home/root/openvpn/client.ovpn

Returned that vim is not valid, so I tried `apt-get install vim` with success. Then then I tried the command again and I got stuck.. it took me forever to understand that I got myself into some weird edit mode... So I assume I have to "change filenames for keys and certificates of client.ovpn", but how.. and to what? Idk, I just skipped that for now.

> openssl rsa -in /home/root/openvpn/spielprinzip.key -out /home/root/openvpn/spielprinzip_new.key -des3

for this I had to do `apt-get install openssl`. But I got an error because the key files do not exist. So how do I get/generate them?

Well, the last steps seem straight forward, but I obviously couldn't try them yet. 
And I'm really wondering where I get my account.cfg and x.opvn from, which I would need to establish the VPN connection.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an issue with SSH. Oh-- why is it erroring? There is no /home/root. You would have /root as your home directory.

Comment: If you can’t get along with `vim`, take a look at `nano`. It does a lot less but is much more beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

For the directories not found: That's because there is no `/home/root`. Instead you have `/root` as your home directory.

Basically use your tutorial but replace everything having to do with `/home/username` to be `/root`. However, I suggest you don't use the root user for it all. It could be a security risk, make sure you drop the user perms used by the OpenVPN server to user & group `nobody`. This can be done in the server's OpenVPN config file `server.conf`

Config File Copy (in lieu of the cp in the first article below):

```
sudo gunzip -d /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf /etc/openvpn
```

Find the lines:

```
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
;user nobody
;group nogroup
```

Replace them with:

```
user nobody  
group nogroup
```

The tutorial you're using is not a very good one. It doesn't go into much detail, I recommend looking at the one I wrote: [OpenVPN - The easy and secure way](https://blog.jaredallard.me/2015/07/17/openvpn-the-easy-and-secure-way/) (Note: That's targeted for Arch Linux) but most of it's the same, or Digital Ocean's [How to Install OpenVPN on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-openvpn-access-server-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Comment: Okay, I installed openvpn and easy-rsa via apt-get. But ´/usr/share/openvpn/examples/server.conf´ does not exist and thus the ´cp´ fails... The socond guid also failed because `user openvpn does not exist` .

Comment: @Forivin Ah, that'd be because I linked the wrong article... Crap. Okay, so yea that file wouldn't exist in `/usr/share/openvpn/examples/server.conf` on a debian system

Comment: See edit for the solution

Comment: Okay, I followed your guide so far. I had to change a lot of things, for example I had to use `/easy-rsa/2.0` instead of `/easy-rsa`... anyway, I just installed `systemd` and ran `systemctl restart openvpn@server`, but I get `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /run/systemd/private: No such file or directory` ... What now? :(

Comment: Is systemd the init?

Comment: I don't know. I found a different command `/etc/init.d/openvpn reload`. This at least doesn't give me any errors. I'm just not sure if it runs openvpn as `server`. And the command doesn't seem to provide the `status` option, so I can't really verify anything. Going on, `./build-key client1` didn't work, so I used `cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0` first, then I could run it, but got this error: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NvEc5R5P Now I'm not sure what to do. Your guide doesn't mention this.

Comment: Looks like openvpn is not running... The command `service openvpn restart` gave em this error: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zEY3bAuk :(

Comment: @Forivin That's solved by sourcing ./var the file you edit for the configuration of the key generation. Not sure on the openvpn failing.